# Are sequential GUIDs useful if they are generated on different machines?

Tags: sql-server

We have many different servers managing tcp connection sessions and aggregate stats for these sessions.  Every once and a while it reports these sessions up to a centralized system for storage in a database (for other systems to query and report from).

Reporting the session statistics is an secondary concern, meaning that we cannot have our server not work with new sessions if it cannot reach our centralized system.  Therefore, the servers themselves need to generate globally unique session IDs so that a session can be tracked across server logs and via the centralized system.

Right now I'm using `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate these session ids.  However, GUIDs cause page fragmentation in indexes in Sql Server due to their random nature.  Normally you would have Sql control the id generation using `NewSequentialId()` as the default, allowing SQL to make sure that it's generating IDs in a more page friendly way.

I can generate a sequential GUID on the machine by invoking the same win32 call that Sql Server does (UuidCreateSequential), but it will obviously not be globally sequential since each machine is generating their own id.

Is it still worth while to generate a sequential id as a database optimization in this case, or is the liklyhood for fragmentation still high enough that it won't make a difference?

Comment: Using sequential ID like that across servers is not going to do you any good. The fragmentation is minimal but there will be LOTS of collisions. I suspect the real issue you have here is that you are using your GUIDs as the clustered index. As you have discovered the fragmentation is staggering with that. An easy solution is to use a different column as your clustered index. Then you won't have to struggle with the index fragmentation as much.

Comment: I may not be totally sure I understand the clustered vs nonclustered difference, but since we have lots of queries that rely on these ids we have non clustered indexes dealing with these Ids, which (theoretically) means we can still end up with a fragmented non-clustered index.

Comment: Why would there be collisions? As per SQL BOL: `GUIDs generated by using NEWSEQUENTIALID() are unique across multiple computers only if the source computer has a network card`, and there is every indication that there are network cards in these computers.

Comment: Perhaps LOTS is an overstatement but I don't know that I would trust the uniqueness across multiple machines 100%.

Comment: Well the only way there is even a possibility of two sequential guids to be same across multiple machines is if two machines have identical mac addresses...

Comment: You say "Normally you would have Sql control the id generation using `NewSequentialId()` as the default, allowing SQL to make sure that it's generating IDs in a more page friendly way." Why not do that here? With this scheme, you're essentially going to create (n-1) page split hotspots in your index (n being the number of machines independently generating IDs). Of course, it may not be a big deal for your environment. As with all things, test it out and see how it goes.